# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: 'branch_task_ids' must contain only valid task_ids

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-taskflow

I have a dag which contains 1 custom task, 1 `@task.branch` task decorator and 1 `taskgroup`, inside the taskgroup I have multiple tasks that need to be triggered sequentially depending on the outcome of the `@task.branch.`

```
PROCESS_BATCH_data_FILE = "batch_upload"
SINGLE_data_FILE_FIRST_OPERATOR = "validate_data_schema_task"
ENSURE_INTEGRITY_TASK = "provide_data_integrity_task"
PROCESS_SINGLE_data_FILE = "process_single_data_file_task"


default_args = {       
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(seconds=30),
    "trigger_rule": "none_failed",
}

default_args = update_default_args(default_args)

flow_name = "data_ingestion"

with DAG(
    flow_name,
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date= airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    schedule=None,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=180)
) as dag:

    update_status_running_op = UpdateStatusOperator(
        task_id="update_status_running_task",
    )

    @task.branch(task_id = 'check_payload_type')
    def is_batch(**context):

        # data = context["dag_run"].conf["execution_context"].get("data")

        if isinstance(data, dict):
            subdag = "validate_data_schema_task"
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            subdag = PROCESS_BATCH_data_FILE
        return subdag


    with TaskGroup(group_id='group1') as my_task_group:
        validate_schema_operator = ValidatedataSchemaOperator(task_id=SINGLE_data_FILE_FIRST_OPERATOR)
        ensure_integrity_op = EnsuredataIntegrityOperator(task_id=ENSURE_INTEGRITY_TASK)
        process_single_data_file = ProcessdataOperatorR3(task_id=PROCESS_SINGLE_data_FILE)


        validate_schema_operator >> ensure_integrity_op >> process_single_data_file 


    update_status_finished_op = UpdateStatusOperator(
        task_id="update_status_finished_task",
        dag=dag,
        trigger_rule="all_done",
    )


    batch_upload = DummyOperator(
        task_id=PROCESS_BATCH_data_FILE
    )

    for batch in range(0, BATCH_NUMBER):
        batch_upload >> ProcessdataOperatorR3(
            task_id=f"process_data_task_{batch + 1}",
            previous_task_id=f"provide_data_integrity_task_{batch + 1}",
            batch_number=batch + 1,
            trigger_rule="none_failed_or_skipped"
        ) >> update_status_finished_op

branch_task = is_batch()

update_status_running_op >> branch_task
branch_task >> batch_upload
branch_task >> my_task_group >> update_status_finished_op
```

When I trigger below tag I get the following error:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: 'branch_task_ids' must contain only valid task_ids. Invalid tasks found: {'validate_data_schema_task'}.
```

I dont understand why I get the error because `'validate_data_schema_task'` is defined at the top of the file. I have tried to hard code `'validate_data_schema_task'` as `task_id` but that gives me the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referring to a task nested in a task group you need to specify their task _id as "group_id.task_id".

This should work:

```py
    @task.branch(task_id = 'check_payload_type')
    def is_batch(**context):

        # data = context["dag_run"].conf["execution_context"].get("data")

        if isinstance(data, dict):
            subdag = "group1.validate_data_schema_task"
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            subdag = "group1." + PROCESS_BATCH_data_FILE
        return subdag
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there documentation about it as well?

Answer (score 1):

Tasks within TaskGroups by default have the TaskGroup's `group_id` prepended to the `task_id`. Meaning since your ValidatedataSchemaOperator task is in a TaskGroup of "group1", that task's `task_id` is actually "group1.validate_data_schema_task". The prepending of the `group_id` is to initially ensure uniqueness of tasks within a DAG.

You can disable adding the `group_id` from TaskGroup to the underlying tasks by setting `prefix_group_id=False` on the TaskGroup if you'd like.

There are some other finer-grain [details on TaskGroups in the Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#taskgroups).